how do i get points to answer a question properly that ppl have ruined!
I recommend always use authentic from source packages not random hacker wanabees!!
I have a much safer solution better than chat gpt bs!
through trile and error! and cant  even reply and answer better than already on site!

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. You may want to read the site help on this topic.

which question are you talking about? ... please add a URL to your post

I assume you are talking about Comments, which require some Rep points, rather than Answers which you can do now. I am closing this question as a Duplicate of one of many questions on this issue...

"I have a much safer solution better than chat gpt bs!" There is (almost) no "Chat-GPT BS" on this site - if you encounter some anyway, please flag for moderator attention and it will be removed promptly. Also, most users here are not "Hacker wannabes" - why would you think that? Thanks!

New users can post answers immediately. If you have a good answer, go right ahead.

Exception: Some busy questions are locked to prevent abuse and spam. New users cannot post answers there. Reputation is required.

New users cannot post comments (which are not answers) until they have sufficient reputation.
